# css sprite in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-sprites

I created a css sprite that show different images when I hover it.

Im using the css sprite in my wordpress page, but I cant seem to get it inside the content.

The images are just all over the page.

Any ideas ? this is my page [http://www.pixeltouch.no/?p=65][1]

This is the html

```
<ul id="toprow">
        <li id="orginal"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="png"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li id="jpgx"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="secondrow">
        <li id="bpp2"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="thirdrow">
        <li id="bpp1"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="fourthrow">
        <li id="bpp05"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="fifthrow">
        <li id="bpp025"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

And the css

```
 #uppg1container{
margin:10px;
padding:0;
}

/*Första raden*/
#toprow {
position:absolute;
}

#toprow li{
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
}

#toprow li, #toprow a{
height:212px;
display:block;
}

#orginal{
background:url('lena.png') 0 0;
left:0;
width:212px;
}

#png{
background:url('lena.png') -212px  0;
left:220px;
width:212px;
}

#png a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0 0;
}

#jpgx{
background:url('lena.png') -424px 0;
left:440px;
width:212px;
}

#jpgx a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0  0;
}

/*Andra raden*/
#secondrow{
position:absolute;
}

#secondrow li{
top:220px;
left:440px;
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
}

#secondrow li, #secondrow a{
height:212px;
display:block;
}

#bpp2{
background:url('lena.png') -636px 0;
left:940px;
width:212px;
}

#bpp2 a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0  0;
}

/*Tredje raden*/
#thirdrow{
position:absolute;
}

#thirdrow li{
top:440px;
left:440px;
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
}

#thirdrow li, #thirdrow a{
height:212px;
display:block;
}

#bpp1{
background:url('lena.png') -848px 0;
left:940px;
width:212px;
}

#bpp1 a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0  0;
}

/*Fjärde raden*/
#fourthrow{
position:absolute;
}

#fourthrow li{
top:660px;
left:440px;
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
}

#fourthrow li, #fourthrow a{
height:212px;
display:block;
}

#bpp05{
background:url('lena.png') -1060px 0;
left:940px;
width:212px;
}

#bpp05 a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0  0;
}

/*Femte raden*/
#fifthrow{
position:absolute;
}

#fifthrow li{
position:absolute;
top:880px;
left:440px;
list-style-type:none;
}

#fifthrow li, #fifthrow a{
height:212px;
display:block;
}

#bpp025{
background:url('lena.png') -1272px 0;
left:940px;
width:212px;
}

#bpp025 a:hover{
background: url('lena.png') 0  0;
}
```

Comment: correct your html first, li tag should be inside a ul or ol tag

Comment: It seems to be working for me... the lena image is reacting to hover states, is that not what you're going for? (btw, you have 3 ul's with the same id (holist). That's probably not what's causing your problem, but it's still invalid html)

Comment: The hover is working fine, Its just that the images are all over the page and not inside the "post"

Comment: That's (probably) because the html isn't valid. Fix this in the (html) editor

Answer (score 0):

As said your html is **[invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.pixeltouch.no/?p=65&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)**
Second you use half pixels, they don't exist
you put the `:hover` on the `a` instead in the `#jpegx`
try this:

```
#jpegx {
    background-image:url('http://www.pixeltouch.no/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lena1.png');
    background-position: -328.8px 0; /*-328.8px is invalid use -328 or -329*/
}
#jpegx:hover {
    background-position: 0  0;
}
```

not tested, but it should help you on your way.

Comment: Im strungling with the validation, but the main problem still left, The images are going over my foot in the wordpress page, Have even write the whole code in a different way, but still problem =/

Comment: Is it your self made theme? or are you modifying a existing template.